# Quicksort byte swaping

Tags: c#, binary, quicksort

I have a mini project on swaping random generated double numbers using quicksort. I have to do it getting it using byte.

```
public override void Swap(double a, double b)
{
    Byte[] data;
    fs.Seek(prevNode, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    data = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
    fs.Write(data, 0, 8);
    fs.Seek(currentNode, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    data = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
    fs.Write(data, 0, 8);
}
```

My swap method

and then the method I am using to do it:

```
public static void QuickSort(DataList items, int left, int right)
{
    int i = left, j = right;
    double vid = items.Get((left + right) / 2);
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (items.Get(i) < vid)
            i++;
        while (items.Get(j) > vid)
            j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            items.Swap(items.Get(j), items.Get(i));
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
        QuickSort(items, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        QuickSort(items, i, right);
}
```

what could be the problem here? The numbers doesn't sort out as expected. Doesn't matter in which order, I just want it to work. Only this line doesn't work: `items.Swap(items.Get(j), items.Get(i));` , my guess is the swap method is incorrect?

Comment: Why are you using a filestream to swap two double values?  Shouldn't the routine simply be : double temp = a; a = b; b = temp.  Then the routine does not return any values.  So you must define the paremeters as out a, out b.

Comment: @jdweng - `void Swap(ref double a, ref double b)`

Comment: @Corak, what would be the suggestion? Didn't understand

Comment: @TautvydasDaunoravičius - The Swap method should be defined like that and the body of the method should be what jdweng suggested. -- `void Swap(ref double a, ref double b) { double temp = a; a = b; b = temp; }`. You **override** the Swap method from somewhere. So you probably won't be able to introduce the [ref keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref). Question is, why override such a dead simple method? You could even declare a `public static void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b) { ... }` somewhere and use it to swap *anything*.